# NHibernate query for subclass with linq or query over

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

We have the following "generic" parameter framework

```
public class EntityWithSettings
{
    public IList<Parameter> Parameters { get; }
}

public class Parameter 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ValueAsString { get; set; }
}

public class IntegerParameter : Parameter
{
    public int Value { get; set; } // Provides ValueAsString
}
```

How can I do a query like the following with linq or query over query:

```
var values = from e in es
               from p in e.Parameters
               where p.Name == "SomeName" && p is IntegerParameter
               select p.Value
```

For sure the above code is not correct but how could I accomplish something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [JoinQueryOver](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-associations). something like (untested):

```
QueryOver<EntityWithSettings>()
   .JoinQueryOver(es=> es.Parameters)
   .Where(p => p is IntegerParameter && p.Name == "SomeName")
   .Select(p=> p.Value);
```

actually, unless you have a restriction on `EntityWithSettings`, you can just do a regular `QueryOver<Parameter>`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var values = es.SelectMany(e => 
                e.Parameters
                 .Where(p => p.Name == "SomeName")
                 .OfType<IntegerParameter>()
                 .Select(p => p.Value));
```